# Windows Event Viewer, how to create group of remote computers?

Tags: windows, event-viewer

We have a file of type .msc on our computer in a domain, that when opened shows this view:
[image: Event viewer shows grouping of remote computers]

However, I can find no way to edit the file to add more computers to the list. How are these files created and edited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This file is not an "Event Viewer" file, but a Microsoft Management Console (MMC) file, which has been set in `User mode - limited access` so it cannot be edited quite a easily. MMC lets you not only show the event viewer, but also other information, such as services, local group policy etc, but in this case it is only used for event viewer of different computers in the domain.

To **create** a new file:

- Open MMC: Type `mmc` in the run window, or directly in search (Win7). You should get a window like this

[image: Main MMC window]

- `File` -> `Add/Remove Snap-in...`

[image: File -> Add/Remove Snap-in... or press Ctrl+M]

1. Select `Event Viewer`
2. Press `Add`
3. Choose `Another computer`
4. Press `Browse`
5. Press `Advanced`
6. Press `Find Now`
7. Choose the computer you want to add
8. Press `OK`
9. Press `OK`
10. Press `OK`
11. Repeat steps above for all computers you want in your list. When happy, press `OK`

[image: Illustration, steps 1-11]

- `File` -> `Save`

In order to **lock** the file so it becomes impossible to edit for a user that doubleclick on the file:

- `File` -> `Options...`
- Set `Console mode` to one of the `User mode - limited access` -options

In order to **edit** a file that has been set to `User mode - limited access`

- Open MMC (Type `mmc` in the run window)
- `File` -> `Open`, then select the msc file
- `File` -> `Add/Remove Snap-in...`